# In an angular.io project, which files need to be commited to source control?

Tags: angular

I generated an angular project using the command line client (ng-cli). For a basic project, it downloads and builds many different files and folders, including 806 node modules.

```
├── e2e
├── karma.conf.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── protractor.conf.js
├── README.md
├── src
├── tsconfig.json
└── tslint.json
```

Which files should be committed to source control?

Comment: if you used the angular cli then a .gitignore as been created that match exactly what should be excluded from source control

Comment: @JEY if you write your comment as an answer I will accept it. It was very helpful.

Comment: Per you request i add it as an answer but i'm not sure it qualify as one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I said in my comment you created your application using angular-cli. By default it will create a **.gitignore** file that will exclude everything that shouldn't be commit to source control. Currently this file look like:

```
# compiled output
/dist
/dist-server
/tmp
/out-tsc

# dependencies
/node_modules

# IDEs and editors
/.idea
.project
.classpath
.c9/
*.launch
.settings/
*.sublime-workspace

# IDE - VSCode
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json

# misc
/.sass-cache
/connect.lock
/coverage
/libpeerconnection.log
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
testem.log
/typings

# e2e
/e2e/*.js
/e2e/*.map

# System Files
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
```

Edit: One can check the current up-to-date version in the angular-cli repository https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/workspace/files/__dot__gitignore.template

Comment: With Angular 9, it seems e2e is no longer added to .gitignore.

Comment: you are right. I won't update this is a really old post and anyone using cli can check it by himself

Answer (score 3):

I would commit everything except for the node modules as it can be generated by running `npm install` if all of the dependencies have been saved in the package.json. For deployment I would remove the tsconfig, tsling, readme and the testing files as it would just slow down the application and do not provide any functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can commit everything except the node_modules folder.